# Android store SMS into Database From BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, sqlite, broadcastreceiver

Please, i'll like to store my SMS into sqlite database. I've done following, but my app crashes.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    if(intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)){
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                Object[] messages = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                SmsMessage[] sms = new SmsMessage[messages.length];

                for (int j=0; j < messages.length; j++) {
                    sms[j] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[j]);
                }

                for (SmsMessage msg : sms) {
                    body = msg.getMessageBody();
                    DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                    dateFormatter.setLenient(false);
                    Date today = new Date();
                    String datemess = dateFormatter.format(today);

                    String sql = "INSERT INTO table_message (DATEMESSAGE, CONTENU) VALUES("+datemess+" , "+ body+")" ;
                    db.execSQL(sql);
                }
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(255): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
E/AndroidRuntime(255): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.exo22.SMSReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2646)
E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3100(ActivityThread.java:119)
E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913)
E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(255): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at com.exo22.SMSReceiver.onReceive(SMSReceiver.java:45)
E/AndroidRuntime(255):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2637)
E/AndroidRuntime(255):  ... 10 more
```

Comment: Can you post your logcat? Thanks

Comment: i just put it my logcat

Answer (score 0):

In SQL commands, strings must be quoted.

However, to avoid formatting problems like this, or SQL injection attacks, use parameters:

```java
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO table_message (DATEMESSAGE, CONTENU) VALUES(?,?)",
           new Object[] { datemess, body });
```

Comment: i corrige but there is my logtcat

Comment: please have you an idea?